# OnEnter, OnLeave, OnGotFocus, and OnLostFocus events never occur for Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have written a test program to try to understand some events for Form and UserControl.
I click on and off of the application and the `OnEnter`, `OnLeave`, `OnGotFocus`, and `OnLostFocus` events never occur for MyFakeForm.
Why not?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyFakeFormAndViewText
{
    public partial class MyFakeForm : Form
    {
        public MyFakeForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyUserControl myUserControl = new MyUserControl();

            Controls.Add(myUserControl);
        }

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnEnter(eventArgs);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyFakeForm.OnEnter(): eventArgs: " + eventArgs.ToString());
        }

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnLeave(eventArgs);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyFakeForm.OnLeave(): eventArgs: " + eventArgs.ToString());
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnGotFocus(eventArgs);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyFakeForm.OnGotFocus(): eventArgs: " + eventArgs.ToString());
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(eventArgs);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyFakeForm.OnLostFocus(): eventArgs: " + eventArgs.ToString());
        }

    }
}

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyFakeFormAndViewText
{
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            //this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.OnLoad);


            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyUserControl.OnLoad");
            //base.OnLoad(eventArgs);
            textBox1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        }

        private void OnMyUserControlEnter(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyUserControl.OnMyUserControlEnter: sender: " + sender + "\teventArgs:" + eventArgs);
        }

        private void OnMyUserControlLeave(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyUserControl.OnMyUserControlLeave: sender: " + sender + "\teventArgs:" + eventArgs);
        }

        private void OnTextBox1Enter(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyUserControl.OnTextBox1Enter: sender: " + sender + "\teventArgs:" + eventArgs);
        }

        private void OnTextBox1Leave(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyUserControl.OnTextBox1Leave: sender: " + sender + "\teventArgs:" + eventArgs);
        }

        private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyUserControl.OnButton1Click: sender: " + sender + "\teventArgs:" + eventArgs);
        }
    }
}

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyFakeFormAndViewText
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MyFakeForm());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the events handlers registered ?

Comment: You see all the code there in the question.

Comment: Because `Forms` usually do not get focus, but the controls on the form do. Is the form maybe complete covered with controls ? Can you click on the form itself, not on a control on the form ?

Comment: I think the `Activated` event might be more what you are after

Comment: @GuidoG: You are correct. I've added `Activated` and `Deactivate` and when I click on and off, they fire.

Comment: @GuidoG: Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Forms usually do not get focus, but the controls on the form do. Is the form maybe complete covered with controls ? Can you click on the form itself, not on a control on the form ?

I think the Activated/DeActivated events might be more what you are after.
They will fire whenever the form becomes active or another form gets active.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell by the signatures (EventArgs eventArgs) that you wrote these yourself.  If VS had done it for you, they would be "(object sender, EventArgs e)"

With the form [Design] view shown, select the lightning bolt icon on the properties window.  Double click the event you want to setup a notification for and let Visual Studio wire it up for you.
[image]

There is NO magic here.. you can also create delegates (event notifications) by hand.  To see what Visual Studio is doing, look at MyFakeForm.Designer.cs and you can see how the the events get assigned.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did use the Designer. I just change "e" to "eventArgs" because one-letter variable names annoy me.

Comment: If you had used the designer AND you also deleted "object sender", then this would not be compiling right now.  You would be getting "error CS0123: No overload for 'Leave' matches delegate 'EventHandler'"

Comment: Oh, you are correct. I think I've tried a number of different ways and have forgotten all I did. Nonetheless, my issue is that I need `Activated` and `Deactivate` as suggested above.

Comment: Overrides don't have senders.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong @Celess but please explain to me how you can "override" a function without the same signature?

Comment: @señor-cmasmas  Because with the override you are already 'this'. It's already the only person itself, that has proper context.  The event version on the other hand was made so that you could have one handler, say for a form that has multiple ListViews, and it can detect which list view for context.  If you type override and then let initellisense fill in the signature, will see that the override version has no sender. In many cases the override version base method, simply invokes the event version with a sender of this. You are the sender.